# Black screen before login

Tags: boot, drivers, display, fglrx, recovery-mode

I'm having some trouble with my xubuntu. It was running just fine yesterday but it's not working today. I remember that I've flipped the power switch during the last shutdown (because it was taking forever); which might have caused the problem.

**System**: Running Xubuntu 12.10 with ATI Radeon 7950 installed.

**Problem description:** Grub is loading up properly, but my display turns black right before I can see the login screen.

**What I've done so far**: Booted into recovery mode and uninstalled the display driver via:

```
sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev*
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try checking the .Xauthority file and lightdm.conf file. Post their output above. Also if any one of them is root try changing their permission. But do so cautiously.